# C++ bind member functions using pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, stdbind

I am trying to understand how std::bind works with member function pointers. So this example is pretty clear to me.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<functional>

using namespace std::placeholders;

struct Foo 
{
    void print_sum(int n1, int n2)
    {
        std::cout << n1+n2 << '\n';
    }
};


int main()
{    
    Foo foo;
    auto f3 = std::bind(&Foo::print_sum, &foo, 95, _1);
    f3(5); //prints 100
    return 0;
}
```

_1 is replaced with 5 and the function is called as i expect it to.

Looking at another example , which combines binding a member function along with std::function from Effective C++.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<functional>

using namespace std::placeholders;

class GameCharacter; // forward declaration

int defaultHealthCalc(const GameCharacter& gc) 
{
    std::cout<<"Calling default function";
    return 10;
}

class GameCharacter
{ 
public:
    typedef std::function<int (const GameCharacter&)> HealthCalcFunc; 
    explicit GameCharacter(HealthCalcFunc hcf = defaultHealthCalc)  :healthFunc(hcf){} // constructor
    void setHealthFunction(HealthCalcFunc hcf)
    { 
        healthFunc = hcf;
    }

    int healthValue() const 
    { 
        return healthFunc(*this);
    }
private:
    HealthCalcFunc healthFunc; // pointer to function
};

class EvilBadGuy : public GameCharacter{
public:
    explicit EvilBadGuy(HealthCalcFunc hcf = defaultHealthCalc) : GameCharacter(hcf) {} // constructor
};

class GameLevel{
public:
    GameLevel(int l = 1) : level(l){}
    int health(const GameCharacter& gc) const   
    {
        std::cout<<"Calling gamelevel health"<<std::endl;
        return level * 10000;
    }
    void setLevel(int l) {
        level = l;
    }
private:
    int level;
};

int main()
{    
    GameLevel currentLevel; // default construct 
    EvilBadGuy ebg3(std::bind(&GameLevel::health, std::cref(currentLevel),_1)); // what is _1 here ?
    std::cout << ebg3.healthValue() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My main source of confusion lies with the place holder _1 above. Can some one please break this down for me? In the above example , _1 was the value passed to it when the function was called , but i cant understand how this is resolved when the object is created.

Thanks.

Comment: I know you want to understand bind_, but in general, I would recommend using lambdas to wrap member functions, much more intuitive and easier.

Comment: `std::bind(&GameLevel::health, std::cref(currentLevel),_1)` produces a function object (let's say, `F`) that is callable with one parameter: `F(param)` calls `currentLevel.health(param)`. This object is then further wrapped in `std::function`, passed around, and finally, called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_1 ... _N are placeholders (which is pretty obvious as they are in std::placeholders.
What you do by using them is to tell which argument to use for which function parameter.

```
SomeClasss obj;
auto f1 = std::bind(&SomeClass::SomeFunction, &obj, _1, _2);
```

This means the first argument of f1 will be used as first parameter when SomeClass::SomeFunction is called and the second argument of f1 will be used as second paramater.
You could also do somthing like

```
SomeClass obj;
auto f2 = std::bind(&SomeClass::SomeFunction, &obj, _2, _1);
```

Now the first argument of f2 is the second paramter and the second argument is the first parameter when SomeClass::SomeFunction is called.

So what you do with

```
EvilBadGuy ebg3(std::bind(&GameLevel::health, std::cref(currentLevel),_1))
```

is to contruct and EvilBadGuy object with its healthFunc beeing GameLevel::health on the object currentLevel. The first argument of healthFunc will be the first parameter passed to the GameLevel::health.

Comment: I am sure you mean f1 instead of f3 , not to nit-pick , but &SomeClass::SomeFunction shouldnt the second argument always be an object here when binding member functions? Cheers for explanation!